# Django Amazon RDS Tunnel Connection with Key File

Tags: python, django, amazon-rds

When I run manage.py, I get this error. Any idea what I did wrong?

django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "myserver.amazonaws.com" (XXX.XXX.XXX.22), port 56133 failed: Operation timed out

Settings.py:

```
import paramiko

private_key_path = '../Mykeyfile.pem'

tunnel_config = {
    'ssh_address_or_host': ('XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', 22),
    'ssh_username': 'myusername',
    'ssh_pkey': paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(private_key_path),
    'remote_bind_address': ('myserver.amazonaws.com', 5432),
}

with SSHTunnelForwarder(**tunnel_config) as tunnel:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': 'postgres',
            'USER': 'myusername',
            'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
            'HOST': 'myserver.amazonaws.com',
            'PORT': tunnel.local_bind_port
        }
    }
```

I've tried localhost and 127.0.0.1 for the addresses.
I can connect easily with my datagrip with the same pam file and configuration. When I step debug, I can see pam file too.